# Constructing a function by recursion

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, recursion

We have the following recursion principle on $\mathbb{N}$

> Let $A$ be a non-empty set and $a_0 \in A$. Let $h : \mathbb{N} \times A \to A$ be a function.
> Then there is a unique function $f : \mathbb{N} \to A$ s.t. $f(0) = a_0$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ f(n^{+})=h(n,f(n))$.

I'm trying to prove that any infinite $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb{N}$ by constructing a bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \to A$ via the recursion principle.

What I want to do * is define

$f(0) = a_0$ for some $a_0 \in A$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ f(n+) = \min\{ a \in A: a \notin \operatorname{range}(f|_n) \}$.

But what is $h$ in this example... $h(n,x) = ???$. Does anyone see how to define $h$ as to match the above construction?

*and this seems to be standard. Same construction is found in D.C. Goldrei's "Classic Set Theory".

Comment: In this case, we can just use a function from $A \to A$ and trivially extend it, can't we?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this, sorry. Could you please explain?

Comment: Take $h': A \to A$ such that $h'(n)$ is the successor to $h'(n-1)$ within $A$, and then extend it to a function from $\mathbb{N} \times A \to A$.

Comment: $h$ isn't required to use its first argument. If $f(n+1)$ can  be derived just based on $f(n)$ without knowing $n$, say $f(n+1) = g(f(n))$, then you can define $h(n, i) = g(i)$ and apply the recursion principle. Aside: in your application, you need to take $a_0$ to be the least element of $A$, not just any element of $A$ and you have to be able to prove the existence of the function $g: A \to A$ that maps each $a \in A$ to the least member of $A$ greater than $a$.